# App Crashing when taking picture on device - uipickercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, photo

I have seen this question being asked many times before but I can't seem to get an answer that helps me. So here is my situation :

I have a user press a button that asks them if they want to take a picture or choose one from their album. When testing on my actual phone the choosing from album mode works, but the picture from camera goes all weird.

What happens : User is shown camera view -> user takes picture -> CRASH

The crash is not one in the console tho... I get a window on top of my xCode window saying :

App stopped unexpectedly due to Memory Pressure.

So I read that I need to resize the image I am getting from the camera before I display a small thumbnail for the user... I am doing that but to no avail... this has now become a consistent issue.

Here is my code :

```
(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

//UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
//[img drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *picture1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[_photoTaken setImage:picture1];

[self updateAppropriateCharacterCount];

[_userInputTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Let me explain what the variables are :

_photoTaken is a pointer to a UIImageView where I want to display the thumbnail. It is much smaller than 320 x 480 though.

Now I also have this method :

```
(void) takePhotoButtonPressed {
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Finally before I did all this funny resize stuff I was setting the "img" variable to another pointer called "image" that was defined in my local implantation. I was using this to check (later in the code) if an image existed.

Any help would be appreciated, or some guidance.

Thank you much

**EDIT**

I also noticed that if I run my app for some time before going right to taking a picture it crashes before even showing the camera - I press take a photo and bam dead....

Comment: You can use Instruments and look at memory allocations/leaks to see where memory is being used.

Comment: If sometimes app crashes before even showing the camera view then you should search for problems elswhere also. Try to figure out memory footprint of your app and locate the most "expensive" objects.

Comment: I have used instruments - I am getting nothing out of it... Mainly because I don't understand what to be looking for. But whilst running allocations and leaks I don't get any "red flags" in the leaks section

Comment: There might not be a "leak" problem - if you are storing many (10 or less will do) raw photos in memory then "legit" allocations can cause the crash.

Comment: Well the app I am working on grabs images from the web and presents them in a feed... so there could be quite a few images "live" at once...

Comment: @rokjarc when you say storing these photos this means they are being stored as a local variable right? Like in cache? Would a solution be when I want to show this camera to clear all images in the app then reload them when done?

Comment: It depends - since you still have to locate the root of memory problem in your app. One thing that might be worth a try is to use a "smart" caching structure like [TMCache](https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache) to store the images. It might seem complex at the first glance but it is pays off.

Answer (score 1):

I have a project designed to be more memory efficient for taking pictures.  The files will be larger than thumbnail, but it usually runs much lighter than UIImagePicker, and the final picture files are significantly smaller.

You can find it [here](http://github.com/loganwright/simplecam)

Comment: MPL - basically, if you add a cool feature to it, that also has to be MPL.  Otherwise, you can use it in your project with standard attribution somewhere.